# Let $f$ a periodic function which is differentiable on $\mathbb R$

Tags: functions, functional-equations

Let $f$ a periodic function which is differentiable on $\mathbb R$

1)prove that the equation $f^\prime(x)=0$ has may solutions on $\mathbb R$

2)Prove that: $f$ is a bounded function

I cant start the problem because i have no idea to how we can solve it

Comment: What is "an infinite solutions" ?

Comment: @ Yves Infinitely may solutions.

Comment: @user281932 Think about what happens in a single period.

Comment: The solutions of $f'(x)=0$ are $f(x)=c$, so what's the relevance of the periodicity ?

Comment: Is it so hard to write four lines and check the spelling ? And is it so hard to check your corrections ?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** If $f(a)=f(b)$ then by Rolle's Theorem there is a root between $a$ and $b$.

**Hint 2** $f(x)=f(x+T)=f(x+2T)=....$

**Hint 3** $f$ is bounded on $[0,T]$ (Why?)

Answer (score 0):

Hints:

(2) Suppose $\;T>0\;$ is the function's period, then $\;f(\Bbb R)=f([0,T])\;$, and since $\;f\;$ is continuous, with Weierstrass we're done

(1) Since $\;f(1)=f(1+T)\;$, rolle's theorem tells us that at some point $\;f'(c)=0\;$ .